# Angular2 No provider for CompileMetadataResolver

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-compiler

So I've upgrade from RC1 to the final release of Angular2. I've done a lot of adjustments but every time I injected `RuntimeCompiler` on my `AppComponent`, this error occurs.

[image: No provider for CompileMetadataResolver]

I have no idea what is happening here and haven't seen the answers for the web regarding this issue. Any help would be appreciated, anyway here is my AppComponent for reference.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { RuntimeCompiler } from '@angular/compiler';

@Component({
    selector: 'content',
    template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>'
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(
        private location: Location,
        private router: Router,
        private runtimeCompiler: RuntimeCompiler
    ) {;

        if (localStorage.getItem('id_token') == undefined) {
            if (location.path().toLowerCase().startsWith('/login')) {
                // LET IT BE
            } else {
                router.navigate(['login']);
            }

            runtimeCompiler.clearCache();
        } else {
            router.navigate(['menu']);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say, that you should add the providers set to the app module:

```js
import { COMPILER_PROVIDERS } from "@angular/compiler";
...

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
        BrowserModule
    ],
    declarations: [ ... ],
    bootstrap:    [ ... ],
    providers: [
        COMPILER_PROVIDERS
    ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This set `COMPILER_PROVIDERS` of providers contains all what is needed by `RuntimeCompiler`. There is an `example` with working `plunker` using that piece of code [How can I use/create dynamic template to compile dynamic Component with Angular 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38888008/1679310) and some more details...

Comment: hi @Radim, that does it! I kept on adding RuntimeCompiler on import and wondering why the error still occur, I'm still new with this version and I think I still didn't understood this whole NgModule thing, anyway, much appreciated man, save me some time!